# Is a HTTP 500 Error normal to display as a result from a semicolon omission in PHP?

Tags: php

Given the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Index PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
class Student {

}


$classes = get_declared_classes();
echo "Classes:" . implode(',', $classes) . "<br/>";

$class_names = ["Product", "Student", "student"];
foreach($class_names as $class_name) {
  if(class_exists($class_name)) {
    echo "{$class_name} is a declared class. <br />";
  } else {
    echo "{$class_name} is not a declared class <br/> ";
  }
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I omit any of the semicolons, PHP emits a `HTTP ERROR 500`, and doesn't even attempt to open the file. This does seem to go against the previous languages that I know (JS, Ruby), that will at least display the webpage, then throw an error if necessary.

My question is, if a semicolon is omitted, is the resulting HTTP ERROR 500 a result of the language's design, or a result of my PHP configuration (using MAMP)?

Comment: You miss understand the concept of that http status. Actually php _does_ open the file and _try_ to interpret it. But since it contains a syntax error (the missing semicolon) it is impossible to compile the code. Which is why such a "server internal error" _has to be_ raised. What else should the engine do?

Comment: The engine could open the webpage, put the error on the webpage, citing which line has an error (does this with JS with the console).  With a HTTP 500 Error, really can't see where the error is coming from. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You miss the point that php is a _compiler_ based language, not an interpreter. That is a difference.

Comment: About you not being able to see where the error is coming from... That is not the fault of the php language, but that you did not read the documentation or any introduction, sorry. Take a look at the http servers error log file, there you can perfectly clear see the bogus line being pointed out...

Comment: One thing you should do is have all errors turned on by default on your development machine. `ini_set("display_errors","On")` , `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and such. This way you can see the error on the browser.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks a lot for the log information. Did not know that, took a quick crash course on PHP and that topic was not covered.

Comment: @Ibu will definitely take a look at that, thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately many self thought "experts" recommend to use error visualization to debug code issues which actually is a horrible thing to do. You cannot develop in a web environment without monitoring your http servers log files. That would be like flying in a narrow cave with your eyes blind folded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolons are almost always required in PHP. Omitting them results in a parse error which will cause the server to return a 500 error. So to answer your question it is a result of the languages design, not your config.

Answer (score 1):

A `500` error, as any other error code (or more generally: status code) which are displayed by browsers, are a construct of HTTP.

The web server invokes your PHP script. If that fails, e.g. due to a syntax error, like in your case, a `500` error is the web server's way of notifying the browser of that failure.

The messages sent by the server along with the error code are kept generic and useless for a purpose. Printing a stack trace to every user might reveal sensitive information about your system's environment. There are frameworks (e.g. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)) which offer utilities to help give meaningful errors when desired, but this could also be achieved using a simple `try`/`catch` block around all of your logic.